# Oracle get foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I'd like to get all foreign keys in a schema, like this.
Let's say I have tables

`users(id, username, pass, address_id)`

and

`addresses(id, text)`

I have defined a FK on users-address_id to the id column in addresses.
How should I write a query that would return me the FK columns like :
users, address_id, addresses, id ?

Thanks!

```
SELECT *
FROM all_cons_columns a
JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
    AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
    AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
WHERE  C.R_OWNER = 'TRWBI'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

found it!

this is what i was looking for, thanks everybody for helping.

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, uc.table_name, uc.column_name 
                FROM all_cons_columns a
                JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                    AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
                JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                       AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
                join USER_CONS_COLUMNS uc on uc.constraint_name = c.r_constraint_name
                WHERE  C.R_OWNER = 'myschema'
```

Comment: With regards, I have added some improved version of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Using @maephisto solution will case a little bug: 
If the `source tables primary key is a composite key` then running the query will result `duplicate unnecessary records`.
Consider T1 and T2 tables:
Master table T1:

```
create table T1
(
  pk1 NUMBER not null,
  pk2 NUMBER not null
);
alter table T1
  add constraint T1PK primary key (PK1, PK2);
```

Detail table T2:

```
create table T2
(
  pk1   NUMBER,
  pk2   NUMBER,
  name1 VARCHAR2(100)
);
alter table T2
  add constraint T2FK foreign key (PK1, PK2)
  references T1 (PK1, PK2);
```

The result of the  @maephisto query will be:
[image]

To over come the problem the query bellow will serve:

```
SELECT master_table.TABLE_NAME  MASTER_TABLE_NAME,
       master_table.column_name MASTER_KEY_COLUMN,
       detail_table.TABLE_NAME  DETAIL_TABLE_NAME,
       detail_table.column_name DETAIL_COLUMN
  FROM user_constraints  constraint_info,
       user_cons_columns detail_table,
       user_cons_columns master_table
 WHERE constraint_info.constraint_name = detail_table.constraint_name
   AND constraint_info.r_constraint_name = master_table.constraint_name
   AND detail_table.POSITION = master_table.POSITION
   AND constraint_info.constraint_type = 'R'
   AND constraint_info.OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are listed in the system view `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022

**Edit**

The columns involved in the constraints are listed in `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS`

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1035.htm#i1575870

Comment: thanks! but from there i can't get the referenced column , just the referenced constraint...

Comment: thanks, but i still don't get the desired output. I'll edit and post my query