# What are the create view conditions in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, create-view

I'm writing a program which is creating view with joining two tables. I have lack of information about how to join them.
When user choose two tables and their columns to be in one view, I need to join them together automatically for the user if it is possible. For this purpose I already found the code to find primary key and foreign key of tables.
With this knowledge how can I say which column of first table should join with which table of second table.
As I found information about this, Primary key of one table should join with Foreign key of another table. Is this right? Can be any other situation. I want to suggest to user that this join may work and they can modify it.

Comment: Do you mean like quering `user_constraints` and `user_cons_columns` dictionary tables ? something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535990/oracle-get-foreign-keys) ?

Comment: Not really. If we have two tables and we want to create a view consisting of both tables. Which columns should join together. Assume that we know types of all the column. How to guess which column should join with which column??

Comment: Don't guess - find it from all_contraints and all_cons_columns

Comment: [Here is an example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94ec9/19) (can be nicer)