# How to find tables with foreign keys that reference a specific table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, constraints

Suppose my database contains the following tables :

- **`table_A`** with primary key *`PKA`*
- **`table_B`** with foreign key *`FKA`*

Suppose also that I have no clue of the content of the database, except that it contains a table named **`table_A`**.

Here is my question : given **`table_A`**'s name, what (PL/)SQL request do I have to make to the database to know that there is a table B that has a foreign key to table A ?

I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: Please post your attempt. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column

Comment: Depends heavily on which sql rdbms you are using - please specify which sql you are using in your tags.

Comment: You need to specify your DBMS. The system catalogs (although *somewhat* standardized) are extremely different between the different vendors

Comment: May [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535990/oracle-get-foreign-keys/5536400#comment30931113_5536400) will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardy solved it ! Many thanks.

The answer lies in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column), sorry for missing it.

Answer (score 0):

On Sql Server, you'd issue `sp_help TableA`

One of the result sets will let you know that TableA is referenced by TableB's foreign key.