# Get All Foreign Keys to Unique indexes from Oracle using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have a table with foreign key to a Unique column in another table. I can see that the foreign key is correctly defined but when I try to get it using below mentioned code using JDBC I dont see it. I have verified that this works when foreign key references a primary key of another table.

So my question is **"How do I get foreign keys to Unique indexed columns in Oracle using JDBC?"**.

```
ResultSet rset = databaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(null, dbName, tableName);

while(rset.next()){
  String column_name = rset.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME");
  String pk_table = rset.getString("PKTABLE_NAME");
  String pk_column = rset.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
  String constraint_name = rset.getString("FK_NAME");

  System.out.println(column_name + " ==> " + pk_column + "(TBL:" + pk_table + ")(CN:" + constraint_name + ")");
}
rset.close();
```

**Additional Info**: Someone had suggested using `getCrossReference` but the problem with that is that I need to know both the source and target tables for the referential constraint beforehand which I don't.
Also I am looking for a pure jdbc api solution that does not employ any special Oracle schema or queries. My application deals with multiple databases but I try to hide it behind a layer of generic jdbc api.

Comment: Hi Mick I'm having the same problem, I'm trying to get all the foreign keys and their tables from a given primary key to know the relationships between tables, did you find anything good enough for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in your case that you use the catalog views.  In Oracle catalog views you will find all the metadata that describe an Oracle database:

http://www.oracle.com/pls/db92/db92.catalog_views

For example, to get all the foreign keys from a certain table:

```
select * from all_constraints constraints where constraints.table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and constraints.constraint_type = 'R'
```

There is a deeper and better answer here:

[Oracle get foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535990/oracle-get-foreign-keys)

Comment: While I think you for your answer, I am looking for a pure jdbc api solution. My application deals with multiple databases but I hide it behind a layer of generic jdbc api.

Comment: Then I will retag your question if you don't mind taking the 'Oracle' tag away

Comment: The reason I kept 'Oracle' there is because the same api returns all foreign keys for MySql or PostgreSQL, but I can see why people following 'Oracle' tag might find it a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getCrossReference` from the JDBC DatabaseMetaData would be the preferred solution. Using `null` or `"%"` as the `parentTable` argument will list all of the foreign keys of the specified `foreignTable`.

However, after taking a look at the [Oracle JDBC driver API](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html) of the `getCrossReference` it would seem that Oracle driver does not specify that foreign keys referencing unique keys will be listed. I tried it out and sadly it seems there is no way of getting the list of all foreign keys using only pure JDBC API. You can only get a list of foreign keys referencing primary keys